# How to swiper slider mousewhell actions

Tags: html, jquery, swiper.js

I have a question.
I want to continue down the page after the slider with the mouse wheel.
So 3 go down after going right. When I go up again, it should go to the left.

```
Codopen https://codepen.io/xlonely/pen/mdXPdxO
```

I think I found the solution. Thx.
mousewheel:{
releaseOnEdges:true
},

Comment: Include the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code if you want to disable the mousewheel for the swiper after the last slide is shown.

```
swiper.on('slideChange', function (e) {
  if (e.isEnd) {
    e.mousewheel.disable();
   }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    direction: "horizontal",
    slidesPerView: 1,
    speed: 1000,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    roundLengths: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    mousewheel: true,
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: false,
    },
});

swiper.on('slideChange', function (e) {
  if (e.isEnd) {
    e.mousewheel.disable();
   }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;

    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/8.1.4/swiper-bundle.css" integrity="sha512-KBVE5XtR1mD+xG5KJdK4mNAvbqLXeD6fbzeSNGLWRQcOdD6sStIZJIUUIN+ng8glwOzQ2x2uRCWkYkqSQSbGvg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
   
  
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Carousel</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<main>

    <div class="container mb-5">
        <div class="swiper mySwiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container marketing">

        <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>

                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the three columns of text below the carousel. This is the first column.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>

                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Another exciting bit of representative placeholder content. This time, we've moved on to the second column.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>

                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>And lastly this, the third column of representative placeholder content.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->


        <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It’ll blow your mind.</span></h2>
                <p class="lead">Some great placeholder content for the first featurette here. Imagine some exciting prose here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>

            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it’s that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
                <p class="lead">Another featurette? Of course. More placeholder content here to give you an idea of how this layout would work with some actual real-world content in place.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>

            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
                <p class="lead">And yes, this is the last block of representative placeholder content. Again, not really intended to be actually read, simply here to give you a better view of what this would look like with some actual content. Your content.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>

            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->

    </div><!-- /.container -->

    <footer class="container">
        <p class="float-end"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
        <p>&copy; 2017–2021 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
    </footer>
</main>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/8.1.4/swiper-bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-hNnjFWCqifslGhuZJVHjXdBund00oDV71mBacLyZYVwmuf+Lx+MGgoG04wehsvhp6FvLYfycrES+b1yh24yvhg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I do this, it won't go back when I go up.
I think I found the solution.
 mousewheel:{
        releaseOnEdges:true
    },